# Does Windows® 7 Home Premium 64-bit supports all versions of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

Does Windows® 7 Home Premium 64-bit supports all versions of Visual Studio 2010?

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page doesn't specify a version of Windows 7. It just states:

> Windows 7 (x86 & x64)

Visual Studio 2010 (any edition) can be installed on Home Premium.

Answer (score 2):

I've used VS2010 Express, Pro, and Ultimate with Windows 7 and haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 1):

YES, but only one version can be installed at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one version"?

Comment: @chrisf Express, or Professional, or Premium, or Ultimate (of Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [it does](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional/system-requirements).