# Does Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit support Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-7

I've got my new notebook installed with Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit OS. Now I need to install Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition to get university homework done. 
However I'm getting error comments when attempting to install.

Please see below error log:

> [08/31/13,19:59:36] Informes de errores de Microsoft: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Informes de errores de Microsoft, but the file is not available.
>   [08/31/13,19:59:36] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
>   [08/31/13,19:59:36] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Informes de errores de Microsoft is not installed.
>   [08/31/13,19:59:36] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
>   [08/31/13,19:59:36] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.

Any clue to solve this issue? Should I install any patch so I can install VS 2010 over Windows 7 Home Premium?

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have Win7 Home Premium 64-bit with VS2010 Ultimate SP1 installed and it installed and works perfectly fine. Though due to crashing on close I had to downgrade from Win7 Ultimate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Windows® 7 Home Premium 64-bit supports all versions of Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815915/does-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-supports-all-versions-of-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

it does support VS2010, i have used it in the past on win7, it seems more like a misconfiguration rather than incompatibility.